# How can I reformat my condition to make it better?

Tags: conditions

I have a condition

```
if(exists && !isDirectory || !exists)
{}
```

how can I modify it, so that it may be more understandable.

Comment: what value does isDirectory have when exists is false?

Comment: exist is Bool type,  isDirectory  is also BOOL type variables

Comment: if(!isDirectory) ... (exists || !exists) will always be true.

Comment: @Shark - What if `exists` and `isDirectory` are both true?

Comment: I read the title as "I have a personality problem, can I erase my mind to fix it". Yeah, I'm tired.

Comment: This should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ThomasEding - given that the question has 8 answers, one of which is accepted, it's probably a waste of everyone's time to migrate this now.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`||` is commutative so

```
if(!exists || (exists && !isDirectory))
```

is equivalent.

Now because exists is always true in the second part of the `||` you can drop the `&&`:

```
if(!exists || !isDirectory)
```

Or you can go a step further and do:

```
if(!(exists && isDirectory))
```

Comment: What was implied but not explicitly mentioned here is that `&&` has higher precedence (at least in most well known languages - there may be exceptions) than `||`. Thus `a && b || c` is equivalent to `(a && b) || c` but not to `a && (b || c)`.

Comment: I think, that `!exists || !isDirectory` is more "understandable", because, `isDirectory` cannot be true if `!exists`. So as a human we will say "if it does not exist or it [exists and it] is not a directory".

Comment: I prefer !exists || !isDirectory over the last one.

Comment: `||` is only commutative if used on values without side effects - if for example used with functions some functions might not get called (short-circuiting) or return a different value in a different order.

Comment: Anyone who relies on the relative precedence of '&&', '||', '==', '!=', etc and doesn't make their intention clear by using brackets deserves to be shot. In all languages, something like 'a && b || c' is equivalent to a comment saying that the author probably screwed the entire thing up in their rush to avoid typing a few extra characters.

Comment: Or, if your language supports it, `unless(exists && isDirectory)`.

Comment: Accurate, succinct and a correct answer to the OP. It's still horrible code to read and understand - in fact, it's harder to understand now than the code in the OP. The expression may be correct, but what is the writer trying to achieve?

Comment: It should be just `if (!isDirectory)`, since `isDirectory` depends on `exists`. It can't be a directory and not exist.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström you don't know that, it could be that calling isDirectory on a non-existent file is UB (or a thrown exception)

Comment: Well, if the variables refer to two different contexts, then they are too terse and need to be renamed.

Comment: @Brendan: Or perhaps the programmer actually knows the language's rules. Hmmmmm...

Answer (score 52):

As a process, I suggest building a truth table:

```
e = exists
d = isDirectory

e | d | (e && !d) || !e
--+---+----------------
0 | 0 | 1
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 0
```

This matches the [`NAND` operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate), which is simply:

```
!(exists && isDirectory)
```

If you don't remember all your logic gates, [wikipedia has a nice reference with the truth tables to boot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate).

---

@Christoffer Hammarström brought up an important point about the state of `isDirectory` being tied to the state of `exists`. Assuming that they refer to the same reference, and that it's not possible to have a state where the reference doesn't exist *and* is a directory, the truth table can be written as follows:

```
e | d | (e && !d) || !e
--+---+----------------
0 | 0 | 1
0 | 1 | n/a
1 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 0
```

The `n/a` is used to represent a state that doesn't matter. Acceptable reductions could result in either `1` or `0` for states resulting in `n/a`.

With this in mind, `!(exists && isDirectory)` is still a valid reduction, resulting in a `1` for `!e && d`.

However, `!isDirectory` would be a much simpler reduction, resulting in `0` for `!e && d`.

Comment: The next step is to realise that `isDirectory` depends on `exists`. It can't both be a directory and not exist.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarstrom, Out of context I can't assume that the variables refer to the same thing, but that is a valid point. The result column should be filled with `n/a` in places where the state is impossible to achieve, and the equation reduced accordingly.

Comment: Well, if the variables refer to two different contexts, then they are too terse and need to be renamed.

Comment: But building a truth table and evaluating it is NP-complete!

Comment: @ThomasEding, I have two quotations for you then, "In theory, theory and practice are the same; in practice, they are not." and "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." you are using the quote out of context.

Comment: @ThomasEding, my point was to keep track of your reality and to solve for the problems you have, instead of trying to solve for the problems you hope to have. In most cases, building a truth table to simplify a bit of logic is a good method. I never said this was a panacea.

Answer (score 22):

For better readability, I like to extract boolean conditions to methods:

```
if(fileNameUnused())
{...}

public boolean fileNameUnused() {
   return exists && !isDirectory || !exists;
}
```

Or with a better method name. If you can name this method properly, the reader of your code doesn´t need to figure out what the boolean condition means.

Comment: +1 for saying something about useful names. But somewhere you will have to reformat the conditional.

Comment: A less extreme alternative, that still conveys intent, is just to name the condition used: `boolean fileNameUnused = !exists || !isDirectory; if (fileNameUnused) { doSomething(); }`

Answer (score 8):

You could just try to nail the ***no-go*** case and bail out if that shows up.

```
while(someCondition) {

    if(exists && isDirectory)
        continue;
        // maybe "break", depends on what you're after.

        // the rest of the code
}
```

or even

```
function processFile(someFile)
{ 
    // ...
    if(exists && isDirectory)
       return false;
    // the rest of the code
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Aren't break, continue, and more-than-one return statement considered code smells?

Comment: @Freiheit It depends on the context. Sometimes an early return statement is used to reduce indentation, thus enhancing readability.

Comment: Best answer - complex conditionals waste enormous amounts of time reading and accurately understanding them. As a result often are "taken as read" leading to insidious bugs.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a truth table as pointed out. Second step could be a [KV-map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) for minimizing the number of terms.

Using the laws of [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws) is another approach:

A = exists
B = !isDirectory
!A = !exists

&& = *
|| = +

**[Edit]**
A simpler transform, because the operations AND and OR are mutually distributive :

exists && !isDirectory || !exists
= A*B + !A
= (A + !A) * (B + !A)
= 1*(B + !A)
= B + !A
**[/Edit]**

exists && !isDirectory || !exists
= A*B + !A
= A*B + !A*1 *//Identity*
= A*B + !A*(B+1) *//Annihilator*
= A*B + !A*B + !A *//Distributivity and Identity*
= B*(A + !A) + !A  *//Distributivity*
= B*1 + !A *//Complementation 2*
= B + !A *//Identity*
= !isDirectory || !exists

Or with double complement (!!x = x):

A*B + !A
= !!(A*B + !A)
= !(!(A*B)*A)
= !((!A + !B)*A)
= !(!A*A + !B*A)
= !(0 + !B*A)
= !(!B*A)
= B + !A
= !isDirectory || !exists

Comment: +1 for using formal rules (I never though that I would see one of these after my first year of college).

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A+%26%26+B+||+!A

Answer (score 5):

I don't like to use "!" when there is more than one condition in the expression. I'll add lines of code to make it more readable.

```
doesNotExist = !exists;
isFile = exists && !isDirecotry;
if (isFile || doesNotExist) 
   {}
```

Comment: +1 This makes it easier to read out as "if is file or does not exist" which is a lot closer to English.

Comment: This is a refactoring called [Introduce Explaining Variable](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceExplainingVariable.html).

Answer (score 1):

As previously indicated, the condition can be reduced to:

```
if (!(exists && isDirectory))
```

However, I'll bet that being a directory implies existence.  If so, we can reduce the condition to:

```
if (!isDirectory)
```